# How do I delete a directory listed in terminal as "Documents\ (2)"

Tags: directory, delete

Using Ubuntu 17.10 (artful). Can't copy and paste directory in terminal.

Comment: What does `rm  -R 'Documents\(2)'` do?

Comment: Or use tab completion. You probably need to escape the ( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory listed in terminal as `Documents\ (2)` in GUI will look like `Documents (2)`, you can delete it by executing:

`rm -r "Documents (2)"`

This is a recursive delete, it will erase everything inside the folder and the folder itself. Also you can use the Tab key to autocomplete the name of the folder in your terminal and also you can drag the file to the terminal and then the path to the file will appear there.